# Splunk Sequence on Following Eval Case Functions

Tags: bigdata, case, eval, splunk, epoch

How does Spunk prioritize conditional case functions? Lets say I have a case function with 2 conditions - they work fine, and results are as expected, but then lets say I flip the conditions. What I see happen when I flip the conditions in the case function the results are not correct. Shouldn't Splunk be able to still check which condition it applies to even though I have flipped the conditions?  Example below:

**Case:** TimeSchedule should output the closest 7th min or 37th min - so every half hour past the 7th min or 37th min from the zipTime_epoch.

**Works Fine as output TimeSchedule should be 2021-03-06 23:37:59.000000**

```
| makeresults
| eval zipTime="2021-03-06 23:35:59.000"
| eval zipTime_epoch=strptime(zipTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")
| eval lastunzip_hour=tonumber(strftime(zipTime_epoch, "%H"))
| eval lastunzip_min=tonumber(strftime(zipTime_epoch, "%M"))
| eval lastunzip_sec=round(zipTime_epoch%60,6)
| eval TimeSchedule=strftime(case(lastunzip_min%30 < 7, zipTime_epoch-

zipTime_epoch%1800+420+lastunzip_sec,lastunzip_min!=37 AND lastunzip_min!=7, zipTime_epoch-zipTime_epoch%1800+2220+lastunzip_sec,1=1,zipTime_epoch),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")
```

**Does not work fine when case in conditions are flipped- output should be 2021-03-06 23:37:59.000000 instead.**

```
| makeresults
| eval zipTime="2021-03-06 23:35:59.000"
| eval zipTime_epoch=strptime(zipTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")
| eval lastunzip_hour=tonumber(strftime(zipTime_epoch, "%H"))
| eval lastunzip_min=tonumber(strftime(zipTime_epoch, "%M"))
| eval lastunzip_sec=round(zipTime_epoch%60,6)
| eval TimeSchedule=strftime(case( lastunzip_min!=37 AND lastunzip_min!=7, zipTime_epoch-
zipTime_epoch%1800+2220+lastunzip_sec,lastunzip_min%30 < 7, zipTime_epoch_epoch-  zipTime_epoch_epoch%1800+420+lastunzip_sec,1=1,zipTime_epoch),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")
    
| table TimeSchedule, zipTime, lastunzip_hour, lastunzip_min, lastunzip_sec, zipTime_epoch
```

Answer (score 1):

The `case` function evaluates each case in the order given.  The first to evaluate to `true` is the one that prevails.

In the example, lastunzip_min is 35.  35%30 is 5.  35 is neither 37 nor 7 and 5<7.  That makes both conditions in the `case` function true so the order of processing is significant.

Comment: Hi,

Let me know if I’m tracking correctly, case will take the first match as the answer?


On my question the query’s - the min of the time stamp is 35, and both conditions are true, since min is not 37 and not 7 on first case, and on the second the modulus operator is working like so 35%30 = 5 which makes it <7 - which makes it also true...

so since both are true it will grab the first match...

adding 2220 in seconds instead of 427 in seconds....

Comment: Correct.  The first condition to match is the one that is used.

Comment: @ZaraZ. - Splunk's SPL manages `case` priority the same way every *other* language does: as soon as a match is found, it quits looking.